# How to append a string at the end of string?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    char* s;
    int size;
public:
    String()
    {
        s = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    String(const char* str)
    {
        size = strlen(str);
        s = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            s[i] = str[i];
    }

    String(const String& obj)
    {
        size = obj.size;
        s = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            s[i] = obj[i];
    }

    String(int x)
    {
        size = x;
        s = new char[size];
    }

    char& operator[](int i)
    {
        return *(s + i);
    }

    const char operator[](int i) const
    {
        return *(s + i);
    }

    String& operator+(const char& str) // append a char at the end of string
    {
        int newsize = size + 1;
        String newstr(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            newstr.s[i] = s[i];
        }
        newstr.s[size] = str;
        delete[]s;
        s = newstr.s;
        size = newsize;
        return *this;
    }

    String& operator+(char*& str) // append a string at the end of string
    {
        int newsize = size + strlen(str);
        String newstr(newsize);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            newstr.s[i] = s[i];
        }
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            newstr.s[size + i] = str[i];
        }
        delete[]s;
        s = newstr.s;
        size = newsize;
        return *this;
    }

    operator int() const
    {
        int m;
        m = size;
        return m;
    }
};

int main()
{
    String s1("abcd");

    String s2;
    s2 = s1 + 'e';

    cout << s2[3];
    cout << s2[4];
    char* c = (char*)"asdfgh";
    s2 = s1 + c;
    cout << s2[3];
    cout << s2[4];
    cout << s2[8];

}
```

My code runs perfectly until the statement `char* c = (char*)"asdfgh"`. After this statement, I am not getting actual output. `s2[3]` after the statement `char* c = (char*)"asdfgh"` is supposed to give `'d'` in the output, and similarly `s2[4]` is supposed to give `'a'` in the output, and `s2[8]` is supposed to give `'g'` in the output. But, the problem is, when I run this program, I am not getting these actual values.

Kindly look into this and tell me where I need to make changes.

Comment: `char* c = (char*)"asdfgh";` ... casting here to get rid of the error about `const` is just ... bad.

Comment: In C++, string literals are constant.  You need a pointer to `const char`.  You're missing the constant part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your `operator+` implementations are wrong.

You are modifying the `String` object that is being added to, and then returning a reference to that object.  You need to instead return a new `String` object that is the concatenation of the added-to and added-from `String` objects, without modifying the added-to `String` at all.  What you have implemented would be more appropriate for an `operator+=` instead.

See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/) for more details.

That said, there are some other problems with your code, as well.  For instance, you are missing a destructor and a copy assignment operator, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You could also consider adding a move constructor and move assignment operator, as well.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    char* s;
    size_t size;

public:
    String()
    {
        s = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }

    String(const char* str)
    {
        size = strlen(str);
        s = new char[size+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            s[i] = str[i];
        s[size] = '\0';
    }

    String(const String& str)
    {
        size = str.size;
        s = new char[size+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            s[i] = str[i];
        s[size] = '\0';
    }

    String(String&& str)
    {
        size = str.size; str.size = 0;
        s = str.s; str.s = nullptr;
    }

    String(size_t x)
    {
        size = x;
        s = new char[size+1];
        s[size] = '\0';
    }

    ~String()
    {
        delete[] s;
    }

    void swap(String& other)
    {
        std::swap(s, other.s);
        std::swap(size, other.size);
    }

    String& operator=(char ch)
    {
        String newstr(1);
        newstr[0] = ch;
        newstr.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    String& operator=(const char* str)
    {
        String(str).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    String& operator=(const String& str)
    {
        if (this != &str)
            String(str).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    String& operator=(String&& str)
    {
        String(std::move(str)).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    char& operator[](size_t i)
    {
        return s[i];
    }

    const char operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        return s[i];
    }

    String operator+(char ch)
    {
        /*
        String newstr(*this);
        newstr += ch;
        return newstr;
        */
        String newstr(size + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            newstr[i] = s[i];
        }
        newstr[size] = ch;
        return newstr;
    }

    String operator+(const char* str)
    {
        /*
        String newstr(*this);
        newstr += str;
        return newstr;
        */
        size_t slen = strlen(str);
        String newstr(size + slen);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            newstr[i] = s[i];
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < slen; ++i)
        {
            newstr[size + i] = str[i];
        }
        return newstr;
    }

    String& operator+=(char ch)
    {
        String newstr(size + 1);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            newstr[i] = s[i];
        }
        newstr[size] = ch;
        newstr.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    String& operator+=(const char* str)
    {
        size_t slen = strlen(str);
        if (slen > 0)
        {
            String newstr(size + slen);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            {
                newstr[i] = s[i];
            }
            for (size_t i = 0; i < slen; ++i)
            {
                newstr[size + i] = str[i];
            }
            newstr.swap(*this);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    size_t getSize() const
    {
        return size;
    }
};

int main()
{
    String s1("abcd");

    String s2;
    s2 = s1 + 'e';

    cout << s2[3];
    cout << s2[4];
    s2 = s1 + "asdfgh";
    cout << s2[3];
    cout << s2[4];
    cout << s2[8];
}
```

Comment: The answer seems to be right but can you make some changes in the code and post for me?

Comment: cuz i have tried but i am still getting the same error

Comment: @XcroodCoding see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it fails is actually earlier

```
String s1("abcd");
String s2;
s2 = s1 + 'e';
```

becuase your operator+ changes its lhs and then returns a reference to itself s2 is now a copy of s1. But they both point to the same 's' char array, things go bang shortly after that.

This would be fixed if you had an operator= that does the same as your copy constructor, but you dont have that

And as Remy points out, your operator+ semantics are wrong anyway. You should return 'newStr'